# WP8 MediaLibrary, view photo in LongListMultiSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to show all photo present in a my device (WP8) in a LongListMultiSelector.
i use this method

```
 MediaPlayer.Queue.ToString();
        MediaLibrary mediaLibrary;
        PictureAlbum cameraRoll = null;


        foreach (MediaSource source in MediaSource.GetAvailableMediaSources())
        {
            if (source.MediaSourceType == MediaSourceType.LocalDevice)
            {
                mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary(source);
                PictureAlbumCollection allAlbums = mediaLibrary.RootPictureAlbum.Albums;
                foreach (PictureAlbum album in allAlbums)
                {
                    if (album.Name == "Camera Roll")
                    {
                        cameraRoll = album;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<BitmapImage> lstBitmapImage = new List<BitmapImage>();
        foreach (Picture p in cameraRoll.Pictures)
        {
            BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
            b.SetSource(p.GetThumbnail());
            lstBitmapImage.Add(b);
        }


        PhotoHubLLS.ItemsSource = lstBitmapImage;
```

In a XAML i have this image setting

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding}"/>
```

It all works perfectly, but I have some questions.

I would like to Zoom on single picture, on image tap i'm insert this code

```
FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null)
        {
            CurrentPicture = fe.DataContext as Picture;
        }
```

but is null a datacontext because I used "Source".

how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which event you've wired up. If you're handling the SelectionChanged event, you can retrieve the BitmapImage (not Picture) from the AddedItems collection in the SelectionChangedEventArgs event arguments parameter:

```
private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        BitmapImage bmp = e.AddedItems[0] as BitmapImage;
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you're handling the Tap event of the Image element in the LongListSelector's ItemTemplate, then you can retrieve the BitmapImage from the sender parameter:

```
Image imgElement = sender as Image;
BitmapImage bmp = imgElement.Source as BitmapImage;
```